# Add cells to my tableView when I make the scroll on it and finish at the bottom of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I've a tableView in a UIViewController. When I load the viewController, is loading the tableView with 3 cells. Every time I make the scroll on my tableView and finish at the bottom of it, I wish that were added to it (other) 3 cells. Just how does the facebook app! Help me please! This is what I experienced in my code (the cells are not added):

```
    -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        //I created an int flag because this method (as soon as it initialize the 
        //table) is called 2 times (because when it load the viewController, is called
        // the method that populates the arrays that contain the details to be shown in
        // the cells and reload the tableView)
        if (_flagCells == 0 || _flagCells == 1) {
            _flagCells ++;
            return;
        }

        if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row){

//phpClass is a class that contain scripts used to connect my app to script php for mySQL DB 
//objsRequest is a method of phpClass that receive a query for input and return an array of //results of that query. cellsLimit represent the cells to be shown (Once every 3 to 3) and //numberOfDequeuedCells represent the number of cells to be added (every 3) that is SELECT .. //FROM .. LIMIT 0,3 .... LIMIT 3,3 .... LIMIT 6,3 ....           
[_arrID addObjectsFromArray:[_phpClass objsRequest:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ID FROM mii LIMIT %d,%d",_cellsLimit,_numberOfDequeuedCells]]];

            for (int i = (int)[_arrID count]-3; i < [_arrID count]; i++) {

//objRequest is a method of phpClass that receive a query for input and return a string that 
//represent the result of that query
                [_arrNames addObject:[_phpClass objRequest:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Name FROM mii WHERE ID = %@",_arrID[i]]]];
                [_arrGen addObject:[_script objRequest:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Gen FROM mii WHERE ID = %@",_arrID[i]]]];

//getImg is a method of phpClass that receive the user ID for input and return an image
//representing the user image
                UIImage *img = [_phpClass getImg:_arrID[i]];
                    [_arrImgs insertObject:img atIndex:i];

//Here is the problem because the rows doesn't be added to my tableView
                [_tableView beginUpdates];
                [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

            }
            _cellsLimit +=3;
            [_tableView endUpdates];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did that myself some time ago. If I remember right, then I just loaded additional data into the Array that I used as container for the data in the table. Once the data was loaded then I redraw the table. That's it.

I think you are getting lost just because you try to do it more complicated.

As for your comment:

```
[_tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.001];
```

or

```
 [_tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

both should execute the reloadData in another thread and therefore should not cause a loop. However, even then you should add the new data just before the end of the table is reached.

Comment: But I have done it this way! But if I do [self.tableView reloadData] method is called tableView willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath: and then form a loop that repeats continuously this method!

Comment: Hmm... I used cellForRowAtIndexPath for that. And I added the data not then, when the last but one cell was reached. I added the data already a number of cells earler. (I used chunks of 10, not 3, and added the next 10 when the 8th of 10 was about to be displayed). That way I did not run into a loop. Anyway, wait for my next comment.

Comment: I've mended the answer.

Comment: Ok now I try! So I replace this [tableView beginUpdates] ... insertRowsAtIndex ......? with what you've written?

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for, but since you were the only answer I can't do anything but thank you :)

Comment: Earn some points on your question and let us know how. I don't even mind if you write an answer where you let others know how you did it and accept your own answer.